# Ошибка в PHP undefined

Tags: php, javascript, phpmyadmin

Помогите мне пожалуйста ! В PHP после авторизации нам должен вывести логин , я его сохранил в куки и далее такая ошибка .

PHP:

```
$login = $_POST["cooklog"];
```

`setcookie("login", $login, time() + (3600*24)*30, "/");`

`$xlogin = $_COOKIE["login"];`

`echo json_encode($xlogin);`

JS:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "functions.php", true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xmlhttp.send("cooklog=" + encodeURIComponent(login));
      alert(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

setcookie формирует заголовок HTTP в *ответе* браузеру. Массив `$_COOKIE` вбирает значения из заголовков *запроса* браузера. Посмотрите внимательно, как устроен протокол HTTP или любую статью про куки и заголовки HTTP. Или просто посмотрите в Wireshark на HTTP трафик вашего кода, там тоже все очень понятно и наглядно, если знать, куда смотреть

Проще говоря, кука `$_COOKIE["login"]` в момент обращения к ней еще не определена. Если быть точным, в массиве `$_COOKIE` пока еще нет ключа `"login"`, и обращение к несуществующему элементу вызовет ошибку

Просто проверяйте любое значение, перед тем как его использовать:

```
$login = $_POST["cooklog"];
setcookie("login", $login, time() + (3600*24)*30, "/");

$xlogin = isset($_COOKIE["login"]) ? $_COOKIE["login"] : NULL;
if ($xlogin) {
    echo json_encode($xlogin); 
} else {
    // Напишите, что делать, если логика в куках нет
}
```

Кстати `$_POST["cooklog"]` тоже желательно проверить перед использованием. Вообще все обращения к массивам нужно проверять, вы пытаетесь работать с тем, чего может не быть, и создаете себе кучу проблем на будущее

Comment: А выводить просто response или response.login ?

Comment: У вас в js коде что-то странное написано, посмотрите http://xmlhttprequest.ru/#use , конкретно "Асинхронный XMLHttpRequest" - у вас response в js коде тоже не определен, и нет обработчика ответа AJAX

Comment: Так я обрезал код , там очень много чего до этого , и всё это есть и асинхронный XMLHttpRequest

Comment: `xmlhttp` - это объект запроса, у него есть функция `onreadystatechange `, она вызывается каждый раз, когда запрос изменяет статус (асинхронно). Вам нужно найти эту функцию и внутри нее посмотреть обработку ответа сервера. Сразу после `send` нет смысла выводить `xmlhttp.responseText` - он еще не отправился и не вернулся )

Comment: Я так и делаю , я обрезал код , теперь выводит null

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в шапке весь код JS целиком, чтобы можно было хоть как-то понять, что происходит